# No block to bake - Number of Rolls differs too

Tags: node, tzscan

Node and services running fine but number of rolls differs in the baking tab to the Staking Balance.

Next baking slot also not available.

https://tzscan.io/tz1P6XUBesrXF2Jp6shmvPqb1M321GKKNcV1?default=baking

Comment: tzscan is shut down. This question is specific to it, this question has little value.

Answer (score 0):

The services shut down, I restarted endorser, baker and accuser. This fixed the problem.

The difference in the number of rolls is the time it takes to recognise the new rolls - I think somewhere between 8-10 cycles for me?

Comment: you should ask a different question with detail information so a good answer can be given.. Stack overflow doesn't follow a forum format. It's a question and answers format. The point for questions is that the same questions can hopefully be searched for and help other people with the similar problem.